# How to bring a job to foreground and then disable job control in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, command-line, jobs

I have a program running in a terminal window. I wish to disable the Ctrl+Z shortcut from suspending the process.

After pressing Ctrl+Z, the command `fg && set +m` unfortunately disables job control only after the process has finished. I could use `set +m` before I start the process but my questions is about the situation where I have already started the process and I need to disable job control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question at Super User, as suggested, and received a [detailed answer](https://superuser.com/a/1834305/1899189).

What worked for me was running `tty` after using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to find out the terminal name, `/dev/pts/0` in this case, and then running `</dev/pts/0 stty susp ''` from another terminal. This does not disable job control but disables the terminal driver from sending SIGTSTP upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to disable the Ctrl+Z shortcut from suspending the process.

Run

```
stty susp ''
```

before `fg`.